# Post id and new keyword value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out how to post the id and value of a new keyword changed inside a row with an input field.

I basically do a mysql query to collect rows of keywords, i then display the keyword inside an input field with a save button next to it. If you click Save i want to post the id and new keyword value for that row.

I can only get the first row to work, a friend helped me with the jquery for getting id only but can i modify to get keyword value too?

MY HTML/PHP

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tags ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id      = $row['id'];
$keyword = $row['name'];
?>

<tr id="<?php echo $id;?>"> 

<td><?php echo $id;?></td>

<td><?php echo $keyword;?></td>

<td><input type="text" name="keyword" id="newkeyword" value="<?php echo $keyword;?>"><a class="savenewkeyword" >Save</a></td>

<td><a id="deleteKeyword">x</a></td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
$('table td .savenewkeyword').click(function(){

var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');   
var name = $('input#newkeyword').attr('id'); 
data = 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name; 
var parent = $(this).parent().parent(); 

$.ajax(  
{
type: "POST", 
url: "update/updatekeyword.php",   
data: data,
cache: false,
success: function()
{
parent.fadeOut('slow');
parent.fadeIn('slow');
}

});
});
```

So just to recap, im trying to post id and new keyword value for each row.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also happy new year for soon ;-)

John

> SOLVED - Thank you DSKVR and Cybermate ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$('table td .savenewkeyword').click(function(){
var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');   
var name = $('input#newkeyword', $(this).parent()).attr('value'); 
data = 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name; 
var parent = $(this).parent().parent(); 

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "update/updatekeyword.php",   
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function()
        {
        parent.fadeOut('slow');
        parent.fadeIn('slow');
        }

    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: You probably have an XSS hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Things,

- you need to grab the **value** from the `input`, not the **id**.

  switch `var name = $('input#newkeyword').attr('id');` with `var name = $('input#newkeyword').attr('value');`
- you should use `.parents('tr')` instead of `.parent().parent()`, while they both work, one is easier to understand without referencing the HTML from the javascript.

Hope this helps, suggested edits illustrated below.

---

```
$('table td .savenewkeyword').click(function(){
var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');   
var name = $('input#newkeyword').attr('value'); 
data = 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name; 
var parent = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "update/updatekeyword.php",   
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function()
        {
        parent.fadeOut('slow');
        parent.fadeIn('slow');
        }
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks dskvr, i tried your code but it still only returns the first row. Every other row also returns the first row. I think its something to do with the parent.Its like the save link is posting the first row only?

Comment: I got it thanks to you and cybermate, i had to change your line to cybermates and change attr('id') to attr('value'). So theoutcome isposted in my initialpost. Thankyou DSKVR and Cybermate

Comment: No problem! Wish I would have caught it :)

Comment: Hey can i only give one answer a green tick?

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. If only there was a half tick :/ ... If you want to make a suggestion, you can always do so on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I just registered with the site but it said i haven't got 15 privileges to vote up yet? How do i get my privileges?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same id for all the input boxes repeating,

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

next to the text field # newkeyword

Change the line:

```
var name = $('input#newkeyword').attr('id'); 
to
var name = $('input#newkeyword',  $(this).parent()).attr('id');
```

Comment: I got it thanks to you and DSKVR, i had to change your line attr('id') to attr('value'). So the outcome is posted in my initial post. Thankyou Cybermate and DSKVR

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$.get('url: "update/updatekeyword.php',{   
   id: id,
   name: name
   },
   function(data)
     {
       parent.fadeOut('slow');
       parent.fadeIn('slow');
     }

});//end of get()
```

Edit: of course you can use $.ajax() //no issue using it ...